# Why are my databases deleting automatically?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I made a database with MariaDB a few days back called fivem. It deleted itself the next day I checked it. Now its just happened again like a day later. I don't understand. Its not the user privileges before anyone suggests.  Any ideas as this is really stressing me out?

Tried recreating the database but same problem

Comment: Where are these databases hosted? Your hardware, someone else's hardware (school?), cloud?

Comment: php and non-parameterized queries / hacks deleting it?

Comment: Maybe you're accessing servers in a cloud which are in a "load balancing" topology. In this case depending on which server you contact directly, which have virtually the same IP, you'll see or not the DB, randomly. Check your hosting configuration.

Comment: @Undo Hosting on a Linux VPS. Its just done it again. It worked fine all night last night.

Comment: @RingØ It is a cloud server. Its a Linux VPS. I don't have access to any of that I believe.

Comment: You're going to need to set up an automatic backup procedure here first, then find out why databases are being deleted second. Change all passwords and other credentials as a protection mesure. Update all your software to the latest version. Ensure your phpMyAdmin hasn't been compromised by reinstalling it. Lock down access to tools like that as strictly as possible, such as via IP whitelisting.

Comment: Tried all of that @tadman and its done it again

Comment: A last resort is to enable the general query log to see if/when someone deletes it. I'd also add a cron job that runs a query that lists all the databases and database connections every minute to see precisely when it gets dropped.